# Akka create two Tcp Connections with the same port

Tags: scala, tcp, akka

I'm trying to create two tcp connections that are bound to the same port. I'm getting an error saying that the `java.net.BindException: Address already in use`. This makes sense since they are both using `18333` as a port, but there must be some way to have two connections on a port that have unique hosts. I'm following along with the [guide in the akka tcp manual](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.15/scala/io-tcp.html#Connecting). How can I make this work? The protocol says that connections need to be created on `18333`, however if I can only have one peer at a time it makes the p2p portion of the protocol useless.

Here is the code:

```
val probe1 = TestProbe()
val probe2 = TestProbe()
val client1 = system.actorOf(Client.props(TestNet3, probe1.ref))
val client2 = system.actorOf(Client.props(TestNet3, probe2.ref))

val local = new InetSocketAddress(18333)

val remote1 = new InetSocketAddress("testnet-seed.bitcoin.petertodd.org", 18333)

client1 ! Tcp.Connect(remote1,Some(local))
probe1.expectMsgType[Tcp.Connected]

val remote2 = new InetSocketAddress("testnet-seed.bluematt.me", 18333)
client2 ! Tcp.Connect(remote2,Some(local))
probe2.expectMsgType[Tcp.Connected]


client1 ! Tcp.Abort
client2 ! Tcp.Abort
```

Comment: You need to lookup how to make akka set SO_REUSEADDR for your socket. That has to happen in Tcp.Connect, so you probably have to pass something like SO.ReuseAddr(true) as socket option.

Comment: Your answer is right, if you want to write a formal post I'll award you the answer.

Comment: I wrote an answer, please do tell me if it was exactly SO.ReuseAddr(true), because I had that in the back of my head, but I couldn't find a doc link.

Comment: Here is the line of code: ```val options = List(Inet.SO.ReuseAddress(true))
    client1 ! Tcp.Connect(remote1,Some(local1),options)```, edit that into your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to lookup how to make akka set SO_REUSEADDR for your socket. That has to happen in Tcp.Connect, so you probably have to pass something like SO.ReuseAddr(true) as socket option.

OP's code to solve his issue based on answer:

```
val options = List(Inet.SO.ReuseAddress(true))
client1 ! Tcp.Connect(remote1, Some(local1), options)
```

[Inet.SO documentation](http://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/2.3.8/akka/io/Inet.SO$.html)

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide enough context for the environment you are trying to run in. When it says "the connections need to be created on 18333", are they talking about the source of the connection or the destination? It would make more sense to be the destination. Your code specifies the source address, when it shouldn't care what the source address is; you only care about the destination address.

Comment: This means both source and destination. The protocol I'm dealing with penalizes peers that are connecting on a non standard port